# UNIX: How does this command change my terminal name?

Tags: unix

I found this online and verified that the command:

```
echo "\033]0;Name\007"
```

Changes my term name to "Name". I'm just wondering why and how does this happen, so that I can tweak this and use it in my scripts accordingly.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Azeem

Comment: Where did you find that?  Was it not part of some sort of posting that said "this is what this is, and how it works"?

Answer (score 1):

Found this (\033 is the sequence for ESC) :

```
ESC ] 0 ; txt ST        Set icon name and window title to txt.
```

In the man page : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html

So, Linux console implements :

> a large subset of the VT102 and ECMA-48/ISO 6429/ANSI X3.64 terminal controls

However this methods does not seems to be portable because it depends of the implementation of the terminal.